# I am having to use Teamviewer and ssh to access a desktop Ubuntu18.04 computer. If I install updates and it reboots, how can I get my session back?

Tags: 18.04

Due to the coronavirus shutdown, I have a computer at my work place that I tunnel into via ssh and also work on GUI wise through Teamviewer. Ubuntu 18.04 tells me there are a lot of updates and that I should install and that it would reboot after. How can I guarantee that after the computer reboots, that I can still access the computer without having to physically go and log in? I suspect I need to do something in the `ssh_config` folder but am not sure what to tweak. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only possible if the receiving Teamviewer does not require a new password. That option needs to be set on the other end not on your end.  I would try to remember what you needed to do to connect the 1st time. If that entails a password be wary... it likely will ask a new one and someone would need to tell you that password.

> Ubuntu 18.04 tells me there are a lot of updates and that I should install and that it would reboot after.

There has never been a time where you are forced to update and forced to reboot. I would wait with the updates unless there is something you really need. From what I read here you already require ssh and teamviewer so more secure it is not likely to get. Just wait with the updates if you want to avoid the risk of not getting a new connection.